# Trouble using functions passing through a numeric reference for dataframe column

Tags: r, function

I'm having trouble with passing references to functions...either using variable names or data frame reference numbers.  Here's an example using the R built in Chickweight

```
attach(ChickWeight)

RTable<-function(x){ 
  x1<- glm(ChickWeight$weight~x) %>%
    tbl_regression(exponentiate = FALSE)
  return(x1)}

#  The following function calls work!

r1=RTable(Time)
r2=RTable(Diet)
merge_d <- tbl_stack(tbls = list(r1, r2))
merge_d   

# The above code works!

####
# But how do I get the function to operate properly passing in a column reference number?
# I need this to eventually use it in a loop.

g1=RTable(2)  # referencing the Time column
g2=RTable(3)
merge_gd <- tbl_stack(tbls = list(g1, g2))
merge_gd  #this should be identical to merge_d
```

I'm sure this is a "stupid" question, but I'm new to R.

Comment: Please add the packages you're using. If you can make the question a bit more [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will help too.

Comment: `r1=RTable(Time)
r2=RTable(Diet)
                                  
g1=RTable(ChickWeight[, 2])
g2=RTable(ChickWeight[, 4])`
Do you mean referencing by column position in the data frame like this? Here r1 == g1

Comment: Thank you!  That is what I needed to correct.   I guess I made the mistake of thinking the attach(ChickWeight) command would negate the need to identify the dataframe.